# Record count of a view and its corresponding table does not match without any joins in view SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a view as below in sql server:

```
use database2
Go
CREATE VIEW view1
AS
WITH date_cte(datecol)
AS (select getdate())

Select Col1, 
       Col2,
       ,....
       ,[Select datecol from date_cte] 
FROM database1.schema1.TABLE
```

on top a table in different database.
The record count of table as well as view using statement

```
Select count(1) from database1.schema1.TABLE -- 15487212
Select count(1) from database2.schema2.view1 -- 13324921
```

Does this problem have any solution?

Comment: question makes no sense. it amounts to data in 2 different databases is different.

Comment: remove the database name if the the table exists in both the databases with the same dataset

Answer (score 0):

First of all... you definitely should improve your code:

```
USE database2
Go
CREATE VIEW schema2.view1
AS
SELECT Col1, 
       Col2,
       ,....
       ,getdate()
FROM database1.schema1.TABLE
```

Why do you use a `CTE` just for the date? Another thing, which may cause your error. You create a view without defining your schema. Maybe your view is created but in a different schema? I've added `schema2` to your `CREATE` due to the fact your querying `schema2` at the end.

By the way. Your select can be improved too:

```
Select count(*) from database1.schema1.TABLE -- ??
Select count(*) from database2.schema2.view1 -- ???
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the issue here was that data was loading into source table while I was running query to count records.
Therefore the count difference was prevailing.
Thanks for your input